# Does WORKDIR create a directory?

Tags: image, docker, dockerfile, workdir

These are the first 2 lines of a Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12
WORKDIR /code
```

Here are some things I don't understand:
From docker's documentation I know that the 2nd line sets the working directory to /code.
Where does this process occur?
Does it happen when docker runs the second line of the Dockerfile, while creating the image?
If /code doesn't exist, does it get created by docker?
Where will /code be created? In the root directory of the image?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [Dockerfile `WORKDIR` directive](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir)

> ... sets the working directory....  If the `WORKDIR` doesn’t exist, it will be created even if it’s not used in any subsequent `Dockerfile` instruction.

I occasionally see SO questions that `RUN mkdir` a directory before switching `WORKDIR` to it.  Since `WORKDIR` will create the directory, this isn't necessary.

All paths in a Dockerfile are always inside the image, except for the source paths for `COPY` and `ADD` instructions, which are inside the build context directory on the host.  Absolute paths like `/code` will be directly inside the root directory in the image, following normal Unix conventions.

You can run temporary containers off of your image to examine this, even if the Dockerfile isn't complete yet.

```
host$ docker build -t my-image .
host$ docker run --rm my-image ls -l /
host$ docker run --rm -it my-image /bin/sh
0123456789ab# ls -l /
0123456789ab# exit
```

(This will always work, assuming the image includes core tools like `sh` and `ls`.  `docker exec` requires the container to be running first; while you're refining the Dockerfile this may not be possible yet.)

Answer (score 3):

The Workdir /path will be created inside the container.

To test this you can do `sh` into your container.

**Steps:**

```
docker exec -it <container-id> sh

ls (Here you will see WORKDIR)
```

If you want to view the intermediate image layers from your custom image

**docker image inspect < image-name >**

Answer (score 1):

The default `WORKDIR` driectory if this is not specified, is the `/` directory.

More info at the following link,
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/docker-workdir-instruction/